# How can I get the multiple attributes according to unique ids in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'd like to retrieve say a list of only ids and genders as `list<DBObject>` from

```
{ "_id": 123 , "gender": m, "occupation": athlete },
{ "_id": 456 , "gender": f, "occupation": basketball },
...
```

Tried using the following but did not work. With query being initiated as a new BDObject gender : 1

```
dbcollection.distinct("_id", query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('mobiledashboards').find({"_id":ObjectId("58d22f68acfecc105733d56a")})
```

Answer (score 0):

"_id" is unique, so no need to call distinct function on it

If you want to get all the documents with gender and _id you can achieve it in following way

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject selectGenderOnly = new BasicDBObject();
selectGenderOnly.put("gender", 1);

DBCursor cursor = dbcollection.find(query, selectGenderOnly); // db.collection.find({}, {"gender": 1}) & _id field included by default in result set

 while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
    // use obj
    // ...
  }
```

It will provide the documents like below

```
{"_id":123 , "gender": m}
{"_id":456 , "gender": f}
```

Comment: How can I return that as DBObject?

Comment: updated..., find method returns cursor, collect it as BasicDBObject and use it for further operations

Comment: how can i return the obj outside the loop?

Comment: initialize an array outside the loop and add the objs to that array in loop.. return that array